# Azure Synapse Analytics - How to create external table or view to point to an Azure Gen 2 Storage Account TABLE

Tags: azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics

I have successfully created both EXTERNAL Tables, as well as Views using OPENROWSET to open and query data stored in Azure Gen 2 Storage - Containers.

Now I want to do the same with Tables stored in the same Azure Gen 2 Storage account.

How do I specify the formats etc to open and query tables stored in Azure Gen 2 Storage account, I have tried something simple like this but the error I get is mostly ... "cannot be opened because it does not exist or it is used by another process."

However, when I paste that same URL into my browser the data is returned via an XML file.

SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET(
BULK 'https://mylakename.table.core.windows.net/MyTableName?sv=2022-11-02&ss=asdd&srt=co&sp=xxxxxx&se=2025-01-31T17:53:54Z&st=2024-01-08T09:53:54Z&spr=https&sig=xxxxxxx',
FORMAT='TABLE')
AS rows;

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found the answer, it is not possible.

However, we can use Azure Data Factory to source relevant records from an Azure Storage Table and output (sink) the records to a .parquet file in a specific Azure Storage Container, then we can use Azure Synapse Analytics to query the records in the .parquet file via SQL (serverless).